# Lua odd string behavoir

Tags: scripting, lua, timezone

I've been trying to find the issue in this for a long time. Two lines under where I get the Month variable, string.find(TimeR, "T") returns 11, but when I used TimeR:sub(Ser + 1) that returns 24T14:19:59+00:00. It's acting as if TimeR never changed, because int he original string "T" was 11 character over.

```
local TimeServer = "http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now"

local TimeR = http.get(TimeServer).readAll() -- Pretend that this gives the string "2013-12-24T14:19:59+00:00"

local function TimeThread()
  local Last = 1
  local Ser = string.find(TimeR, "-")
  local Year = TimeR:sub(Last, Ser - 1)
  TimeR = TimeR:sub(Ser + 1)
  Ser = string.find(TimeR, "-")

  local Month = TimeR:sub(Last, Ser - 1)
  TimeR = TimeR:sub(Ser + 1)
  Ser = string.find(TimeR, "T")

  local Day = TimeR:sub(Last, Ser - 1)
  TimeR = TimeR:sub(Ser + 1)
  Ser = string.find(TimeR, ":")

  local Hour = TimeR:sub(Last, Ser - 1)
  TimeR = TimeR:sub(Ser + 1)
  Ser = string.find(TimeR, ":")

  local Minute = TimeR:sub(Last, Ser - 1)
  TimeR = TimeR:sub(Ser + 1)
  Ser = string.find(TimeR, "+")

  local Second = TimeR:sub(Last, Ser - 1)
  print(Year .. ", " .. Month .. ", " .. Day .. ", " .. Hour .. ", " .. Minute .. ", " .. Second)
end 

TimeThread()
```

Comment: What output do you get? I get `2013, 12, 24, 14, 19, 59` which looks good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  this one-liner:

```
Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second = TimeR:match("(.-)%-(.-)%-(.-)T(.-):(.-):(.-)%+")
```